# Docu sign api integration in bubble

Tags: bubble.io

Hey everyone anyone with an idea of how to integrate docu sign into bubble

I want to get my app users to be directed to DocuSign for signing documents but I am having difficulties connecting the API to Bubble. I have tried the plugins but it seems DocuSign now requires Oauth to connect, so am thinking of using the API connector but just do not know how to do that anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, integrating DocuSign with Bubble requires setting up OAuth now, I think.

So, create an app within DocuSign to get your API keys. In Bubble, tap into the API Connector to connect with DocuSign. Set up OAuth2 in the API Connector using the details from DocuSign. Pay attention to the redirect URI—it's usually formatted as https://yourapp.bubbleapps.io/api/1.1/oauth_redirect

Once you're set with authentication, you should be able to make API calls.

Hope that helped!